# How to prevent windowpopup displacement after showing soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm created WindowPopup, with edittext. And when i focused on it, soft keyboard show and displace this popup above the top bounds, so i can't see what i'm typing. I want to show keyboard without any displace of views, just above them.
I read that i can change softInputMode for it, so i'm created class which extends from EditText, and tried to change inputMode in onFocusListener, but it didn't help.

```
setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View veiw, boolean has_focus) {

        if (has_focus) {
            //Try to change input mode to prevent displacing
            ((Activity) getContext()).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
        } else {
            //.. return back previous input mode
        }

});
```

I did so, because i need such behavior only in this popup, but i even try to change action attribute in my manifets file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Can i show keyboard without any displacing of view?

P.S. i'm using Android API 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PopupWindow creates popup view, it sets to it new WindowManager.LayoutParams with softInputMode, which is overwrites behavior of Window.softInputMode. Here piece of code from PopupWindow

```
private WindowManager.LayoutParams createPopupLayout(IBinder token) {

    WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    p.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    p.width = mLastWidth = mWidth;
    p.height = mLastHeight = mHeight;
    if (mBackground != null) {
        p.format = mBackground.getOpacity();
    } else {
        p.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
    p.flags = computeFlags(p.flags);
    p.type = mWindowLayoutType;
    p.token = token;
    /*mSoftInputMode is the private field which is by default equals
      to WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED 
    */
    p.softInputMode = mSoftInputMode;
}
```

So to change softInputMode you need just to call public method of PopupWindow

```
setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

And there is no need to remember previous soft input method, because this behavior will be only for this PopupWindow